# Numbers help creating aggregates

Tags: apple-numbers

I have a table with rows of multiple types. How do I create another table from it so that the rows in this table reflect the sum of all rows of each type from the previous table.

For e.g. I have a Table1 with 5 rows of type A, 6 rows of Type B. I want to create a table (Table2) that contains one row of type A (which is sum of all the 5 rows from Table1) and one row of type B (again this is the sum of all 6 rows from Table1).